# Run Service Control (sc.exe) command on secure port

Tags: windows, port, windows-service, dmz

Our team runs the following commands to turn on and off Windows Services (e.g. JBoss Native) from the Windows command line as well as through source code in a program.  It connects to a remote box.  We are now placing this box (\DEV-A1) into our DMZ.  How can we still run this command remotely but use a secure port?

```
sc \\DEV-A1 stop JBAS50SVC
sc \\DEV-A1 start JBAS50SVC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sc.exe` uses [RPC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738291(v=ws.10).aspx) to connect to remote hosts; RPC calls always start with a control connection to TCP port 135, but then another connection is opened using a random dynamic port to carry out the actual RPC call; the range of these dynamic ports [can be limited](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/154596), but how many of them are needed depends heavily on what the computer is doing.

Also, keep in mind that if the server is a domain member (which it probably is, since you are controlling it remotely with a command that uses integrated authentication), you will anyway need to open lots of ports in your firewall(s) in order for it to operate properly.

Comment: Looks like TCP protocol is secure!  Thanks Massimo!

Comment: ........what?!?

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: "Looks like TCP protocol is secure" means... what, exactly?

Comment: Well, at first, our security department was saying if it was not secure, they wouldn't allow it, because it's in the DMZ.  I am not sure how to tell if the protocols themselves are secure/encrypted, or if the individual ports are.  Also, they had never heard of sc.exe before to turn on/off Windows Services.  They were more familiar with PowerShell.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using remote PowerShell, but if you want to use SC, then you will have to allow the RPC protocol.